# Linux cgroups cpuset w/ subs causes cgconfig not to start

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, cgroup

I am having a problem trying to separate 2 groups using cpuset subsystem. This works fine, however if i go to add a subgroup to that group (in this case -- user1), cgconfig will fail to start with "Failed to remove a non-empty group". Removing group abusers/user1 will start perfectly. However, this breaks what i am trying todo.

Here is an example cgconfig that will fail to start.

CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64
libcgroup-0.40.rc1-5.el6_5.1.x86_64
Inside of a VM.

```
mount {
    cpuset  = /cgroup/cpuset;
    cpu = /cgroup/cpu;
    cpuacct = /cgroup/cpuacct;
    memory  = /cgroup/memory;
    devices = /cgroup/devices;
    freezer = /cgroup/freezer;
    net_cls = /cgroup/net_cls;
    blkio   = /cgroup/blkio;
}

group normal {

  blkio {
                blkio.throttle.write_bps_device="253:0 72428800";
                blkio.throttle.read_bps_device="253:0  72428800";
                blkio.reset_stats="";
                blkio.weight="700";
                blkio.weight_device="";

  }
  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = "1673003008";
    memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes="1673003008";
  }

  cpuset {
        cpuset.mems = "0";
        cpuset.cpus = "0-2";
     }
}


group abusers {

cpu {}
blkio {}

  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = "38442369024";
    memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes="81203822592";
  }

  cpuset {
        cpuset.mems = "0";
        cpuset.cpus = "3";
     }

}


group abusers/user1 {
  cpu {
    cpu.shares = 200;
    cpu.cfs_quota_us = 10000;
    cpu.cfs_period_us = 100000;
  }

  blkio {
                blkio.throttle.write_bps_device="253:2 10485760";
                blkio.throttle.read_bps_device="253:2  10485760";
                blkio.reset_stats="";
                blkio.weight="100";
                blkio.weight_device="";

  }


  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes = "1024M";
    memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes="1280M";
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What device is at 253:0? My guess is that particular device doesn't have rw permission for non-root users. So either you have the wrong device for what you're trying to throttle, or you need to set rw permissions on it for non-root users.